# Reading a ppm (P6) image in C

Tags: c, ppm

Here's the code(it's partially in Portuguese). My goal is to count how many objects are in it.

Basically I'm reading a P6, saving the background color, then allocating dynamically and reading it, and finally comparing all of the 2d array with the background color, if the pixel is different it will change it for the background color and check his neighborhood, if some of the neighbors are in the same condition, then the process is repeated, the thing is:
for some reason the outcome is saying that there are a lot more pixels different from the background color than it should be, can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{

    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;

} PIXEL;

void defmtx(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *dim1, int *dim2, PIXEL *cdf);
void examinar(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *dim1, int *dim2, PIXEL *cdf, int *cont);
void examinarnv2(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *i, int *j, PIXEL *cdf, int *dim1, int *dim2);

int main(){

    int dim1, dim2, max;
    long int aux;
    FILE *im;
    unsigned char img[100], p6[3], qbrlin;
    PIXEL **matrix, cdf;

    printf("Caminho da imagem:\n");
    gets(img);
    //Mudar gets dps 

    im = fopen(img,"r");

    if( im == NULL ){

        printf("Erro 1\n"); //arquivo nao existe ou endereço errado
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else{

        fscanf(im,"%s",&p6);

            if ( strcmp(p6,"P6") != 0 ){
                printf("\nArquivo nao e uma imagem\n");
                exit(1);
            }

        fscanf(im,"%i %i %i", &dim1, &dim2, &max);
        //dimensões da matriz
        fscanf(im,"%c%c%c%c",&qbrlin, &cdf.r, &cdf.g, &cdf.b);  
        defmtx(im, matrix, &dim1, &dim2, &cdf);
        //printf("\n%i %i %i\n", dim1, dim2, max);
        //printf("\n%hhu %hhu %hhu\n",cdf.r, cdf.g, cdf.b);

    }

    fclose(im);

    return 0;
}

void defmtx(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *dim1, int *dim2, PIXEL *cdf){

    int n = 0,j = 0, cont = 0;
    long int aux;

    matrix = (PIXEL **)malloc( (*dim1) * sizeof(PIXEL *) );
    //Alocando a matriz

    while ( n < (*dim1) ){

        j = 0;
        matrix[n] = (PIXEL *) malloc ((*dim2) * sizeof(PIXEL));
        //Alocando a matriz
        if(n == 0)
            j++;
        while( j < (*dim2) ){

            //aux = ftell(im);
            //printf(" %i ",aux);
            fread( &matrix[n][j].r,sizeof(unsigned char),1,im );
            fread( &matrix[n][j].g,sizeof(unsigned char),1,im );
            fread( &matrix[n][j].b,sizeof(unsigned char),1,im );

            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }

    matrix[0][0].r = cdf->r;
    matrix[0][0].g = cdf->g;
    matrix[0][0].b = cdf->b;

    examinar(im, matrix, dim1, dim2, cdf, &cont );

}

void examinar(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *dim1, int *dim2, PIXEL *cdf, int *cont){

    int i = 0,j = 0,flag = 0;
    long int aux;

    while( i < (*dim1) ){
        j = 0;

        while( j < (*dim2) ){

            if ( (matrix[i][j].r != cdf->r) || (matrix[i][j].g != cdf->g) || (matrix[i][j].b != cdf->b)){

                (*cont)++;
                flag++;
                aux = ftell(im);
                printf("\n%i\n", aux);
                //printf("%i %i , %i %i %i\n",i,j,matrix[i][j].r,matrix[i][j].g,matrix[i][j].b);
                matrix[i][j].r = cdf->r;
                matrix[i][j].g = cdf->g;
                matrix[i][j].b = cdf->b;
                examinarnv2(im, matrix, &i, &j, cdf, dim1, dim2);
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }

       if ( flag == 1 ){
             flag--;
             break;     
            }
            i++;
        }

    if (flag == 0) {   
        if ( ( i == (*dim1) ) && ( j == (*dim2) ) ){
            printf("\nnum obj: %i\n", *cont);
        }

        else {
            examinar(im, matrix, dim1, dim2, cdf, cont);
        }
    }
}

void examinarnv2(FILE *im, PIXEL **matrix, int *i, int *j, PIXEL *cdf, int *dim1, int *dim2){

    // Arrumar isso depois //

    int k=0;

    if( ( (*i) > 0 ) && ( (*i) <= ( (*dim1) - 1 ) )){

        if ( ( matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].r != cdf->r ) || ( matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].g != cdf->g ) || ( matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].b != cdf->b ) ){

            k = (*i) - 1;

            matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].r = cdf->r;
            matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].g = cdf->g;
            matrix[(*i)-1][(*j)].b = cdf->b;

            examinarnv2(im, matrix, &k , j, cdf, dim1, dim2);
        }
    }

    if( ( (*j) > 0) && ( (*j) <= ( (*dim2) - 1 ) )){

        if ( ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].r != cdf->r ) || ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].g != cdf->g ) || ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].b != cdf->b ) ){

            k = (*j)-1;

            matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].r = cdf->r;
            matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].g = cdf->g;
            matrix[(*i)][(*j)-1].b = cdf->b;

            examinarnv2(im, matrix, i , &k, cdf, dim1, dim2);
        }
    }

    if( ( (*i) < ( (*dim1) - 1 ) ) && ( (*i) >= 0) ){

        if ( ( matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].r != cdf->r ) || ( matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].g != cdf->b ) || ( matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].b != cdf->b ) ){

            k = (*i) + 1;
            matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].r = cdf->r;
            matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].g = cdf->g;
            matrix[(*i)+1][(*j)].b = cdf->b;
            examinarnv2(im, matrix, &k , j, cdf, dim1, dim2);

        }

    }

    if( ( (*j) < ( (*dim2) - 1 ) ) && ( (*j) >= 0 ) ){

        if ( ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].r != cdf->r ) || ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].g != cdf->g ) || ( matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].b != cdf->b ) ){

            k = (*j) + 1;

            matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].r = cdf->r;
            matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].g = cdf->g;
            matrix[(*i)][(*j)+1].b = cdf->b;

            examinarnv2(im, matrix, i, &k, cdf, dim1, dim2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest passing your arguments as `int` instead of `int*`. It makes it hard to read your code.  And it's inefficient to be dereferencing all over the place when just a standard int will do.

Comment: This code is a bit too much to digest, but your ".. if the pixel is different it will change it for the background color .." makes me wonder if you are counting some pixels twice - once as "foreground", and after the change again as "background".